# JavaScript - DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I have the following code:

```
23/09/2014 - 09:15 (DD/MM/YYYY - HH:SS)
```

I need to use JS to reformat in milliseconds.

Comment: You need `Javascript`, not `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dateString = "23/09/2014 - 09:15",
    dateArgs = dateString.match(/\d{2,4}/g),
    year = dateArgs[2],
    month = parseInt(dateArgs[1]) - 1,
    day = dateArgs[0],
    hour = dateArgs[3],
    minutes = dateArgs[4];

var milliseconds = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes).getTime();
```

Comment: Andrew, I don't know if your code is working properly... Its returning "1414576800000" instead "1411988400000".

Comment: @AndreFelipe, I've updated answer. Unfortunately I forgot that Date constructor accepts month argument in [0-11] range

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/jpkkngjw/

```
// getTime() returns milliseconds since epoch
moment("23/09/2014 - 09:15", "DD/MM/YYYY - HH:SS").toDate().getTime()
```

Here are some other examples of using Momento

```
moment().format();                                // "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" (ISO 8601)
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"
moment().format("ddd, hA");                       // "Sun, 3PM"
moment('gibberish').format('YYYY MM DD');         // "Invalid date"
```